# How i can parse multiline json file in logstash to hash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a valid multiline JSON file. I want to parse it, and to assign it keys as field names, and values as field values.

Is it possible to do automatically?

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/logstash/xunit.json"
    codec => json
  }
} 

output {
  stdout {}
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    codec => "json"
    host => "kibana.dev"
    port => "9200"
  }
}
```

After using this config, i see that something was added.. but i can't see that fields from my json appeared. Is it possible to grab name, severity, status, start & stop dates?

My json example:

```
[ 
  {
    "uid" : "441d1d1dd296fe60",
    "name" : "test_buylinks",
    "title" : "Test buylinks",
    "time" : {
      "start" : 1419621623182,
      "stop" : 1419621640491,
      "duration" : 17309
    },
    "severity" : "NORMAL",
    "status" : "FAILED"
  }, 
  {
    "uid" : "a88c89b377aca0c9",
    "name" : "test_buylinks",
    "title" : "Test buylinks",
    "time" : {
      "start" : 1419621623182,
      "stop" : 1419621640634,
      "duration" : 17452
    },
    "severity" : "NORMAL",
    "status" : "FAILED"
  }, 
  {
    "uid" : "32c3f8b52386c85c",
    "name" : "test_buylinks",
    "title" : "Test buylinks",
    "time" : {
      "start" : 1419621623185,
      "stop" : 1419621640826,
      "duration" : 17641
    },
    "severity" : "NORMAL",
    "status" : "FAILED"
  } 
]
```

Comment: Isn't this one just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753921/logstash-does-not-parse-json?