# Logstash does not parse json

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

When i see results in Kibana, i see that there are no fields from JSON, more over, `message` field contains only `"status" : "FAILED"`.

Is it possible to parse fields from json and to show them in Kibana?
I have following config:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "json"
    path => "/home/logstash/test.json"
    codec => json
    sincedb_path => "/home/logstash/sincedb"
  }
} 

output {
  stdout {}
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    codec => "json"
    host => "elasticsearch.dev"
    port => "9200"
  }
}
```

And following JSON file:

```
[{"uid":"441d1d1dd296fe60","name":"test_buylinks","title":"Testbuylinks","time":{"start":1419621623182,"stop":1419621640491,"duration":17309},"severity":"NORMAL","status":"FAILED"},{"uid":"a88c89b377aca0c9","name":"test_buylinks","title":"Testbuylinks","time":{"start":1419621623182,"stop":1419621640634,"duration":17452},"severity":"NORMAL","status":"FAILED"},{"uid":"32c3f8b52386c85c","name":"test_buylinks","title":"Testbuylinks","time":{"start":1419621623185,"stop":1419621640826,"duration":17641},"severity":"NORMAL","status":"FAILED"}]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. you need to add a filter to your config, something like this.

```
filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}
```

It's described pretty well in the docs [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/json)

**EDIT**
The json codec doesn't seem to like having an array passed in. A single element works with this config:

**Input:**

```
{"uid":"441d1d1dd296fe60","name":"test_buylinks","title":"Testbuylinks","time":{"start":1419621623182,       "stop":1419621640491,"duration":17309      },      "severity":"NORMAL",      "status":"FAILED"   }
```

**Logstash Result:**

```
{
      "message" => "{\"uid\":\"441d1d1dd296fe60\",\"name\":\"test_buylinks\",\"title\":\"Testbuylinks\",\"time\":{\"start\":1419621623182,       \"stop\":1419621640491,\"duration\":17309      },      \"severity\":\"NORMAL\",      \"status\":\"FAILED\"   }",
     "@version" => "1",
   "@timestamp" => "2015-02-26T23:25:12.011Z",
         "host" => "emmet.local",
          "uid" => "441d1d1dd296fe60",
         "name" => "test_buylinks",
        "title" => "Testbuylinks",
         "time" => {
          "start" => 1419621623182,
           "stop" => 1419621640491,
       "duration" => 17309
   },
     "severity" => "NORMAL",
       "status" => "FAILED"
```

}

Now with an array:

**Input**

```
[{"uid":"441d1d1dd296fe60","name":"test_buylinks","title":"Testbuylinks","time":{"start":1419621623182,       "stop":1419621640491,"duration":17309      },      "severity":"NORMAL",      "status":"FAILED"   }, {"uid":"441d1d1dd296fe60","name":"test_buylinks","title":"Testbuylinks","time":{"start":1419621623182,       "stop":1419621640491,"duration":17309      },      "severity":"NORMAL",      "status":"FAILED"   }]
```

**Result:**

```
Trouble parsing json {:source=>"message", :raw=>"[{\"uid\":\"441d1d1dd296fe60\",\"name\":\"test_buylinks\",\"title\":\"Testbuylinks\",\"time\":{\"start\":1419621623182,       \"stop\":1419621640491,\"duration\":17309      },      \"severity\":\"NORMAL\",      \"status\":\"FAILED\"   }, {\"uid\":\"441d1d1dd296fe60\",\"name\":\"test_buylinks\",\"title\":\"Testbuylinks\",\"time\":{\"start\":1419621623182,       \"stop\":1419621640491,\"duration\":17309      },      \"severity\":\"NORMAL\",      \"status\":\"FAILED\"   }]", :exception=>#<TypeError: can't convert Array into Hash>, :level=>:warn}
{
      "message" => "[{\"uid\":\"441d1d1dd296fe60\",\"name\":\"test_buylinks\",\"title\":\"Testbuylinks\",\"time\":{\"start\":1419621623182,       \"stop\":1419621640491,\"duration\":17309      },      \"severity\":\"NORMAL\",      \"status\":\"FAILED\"   }, {\"uid\":\"441d1d1dd296fe60\",\"name\":\"test_buylinks\",\"title\":\"Testbuylinks\",\"time\":{\"start\":1419621623182,       \"stop\":1419621640491,\"duration\":17309      },      \"severity\":\"NORMAL\",      \"status\":\"FAILED\"   }]",
     "@version" => "1",
   "@timestamp" => "2015-02-26T23:28:21.195Z",
         "host" => "emmet.local",
         "tags" => [
       [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
   ]
}
```

This looks like a bug in the codec, can you change your messages to an object rather than an array?

Comment: I've read this docs, but filter did not help. The result is the same. As i understand, this definition says: message contains valid JSON object you can use as hash.

It's nice. But anyway, i still do not see valid JSON in message. Only parts.

Comment: I think the issue might be that your message is an array and the json codec is expecting an object at the root

Comment: wow, perhaps we can report this a bug... Anyway, you were right - filter is a solution. https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/issues/2702

Comment: Seems they are aware of it, from the source code:       # TODO(sissel): Note, this will not successfully handle json lists
      # like your text is '[ 1,2,3 ]' JSON.parse gives you an array (correctly)
      # which won't merge into a hash. If someone needs this, we can fix it
      # later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Now things got clear. Anyway, i've reported in my ticket on github

Answer (score 2):

Try the `json_lines` codec instead of `json`.  This must have been added recently.  In your particular case, you'd first want to change your output from a list of json to newline-delimited json.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/codecs/json_lines

> This codec will decode streamed JSON that is newline delimited. For
>   decoding JSON payload in the redis input for example, use the json
>   codec instead. Encoding will emit a single JSON string ending in a
>   '\n'

Answer (score 2):

Reading in a file containing a JSON array is way harder than it should be. Below is a working pipeline configuration

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "cat /path/file_containing_json_array.txt"
    codec => "json"
    interval => 3600
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```