# Logstash scala log parsing

Tags: scala, configuration, logstash

I've got a problem with logstash. I use logback, logstash, kibana and elasticsearch (docker as logstash input source)

The problem is I have no idea how can I write a correct config file for logstash to get some interesting information.

The single scala log looks like this:

> [INFO] [05/06/2016 13:58:31.789] [integration-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] [akka://integration/user/InstanceSupervisor/methodRouter/outDispatcher] sending msg: PublishMessage(instance,vouchers,Map(filePath -> /home/mateusz/JETBLUETESTING.csv, importedFiles -> Map(JETBLUETESTING.csv -> Map(status -> DoneStatus, processed -> 1, rows -> 5))),#contentHeader(content-type=application/octet-stream, content-encoding=null, headers=null, delivery-mode=2, priority=0, correlation-id=null, reply-to=null, expiration=null, message-id=null, timestamp=null, type=null, user-id=null, app-id=null, cluster-id=null)

I'd like to get something like tag [INFO], timestamp and of course the whole log in a single kibana result.

As for now i don't event know how exactly the log looks like (because its parsed by logback). Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated, because im stuck on this problem for few days.

Answer (score 0):

When learning logstash it's best to find a debugger to help experiment (grok) with patterns. The standard appears to be hosted [here](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). The site allows you to post a snippet from your logs, and then allows you to experiment with either pre-defined or custom patterns. The pre-defined patterns can be found [here](https://github.com/garethr/logstashpatterns/blob/master/patterns/logstash).

I had the same issue recently when trying to find out what logback was sending to logstash. I found that logback was able to convert the logs to json.A snippet I found useful is:

```
filter{
    json{
      source => "message"
    }
}
```

Which I found in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753921/logstash-does-not-parse-json)

Once you can see the logs, it makes it much easier to experiment with patterns.

Hope this is useful.