# Logstash not parsing JSON

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Logstash config

```
input {
    file{
        path => "/home/folder/stash/data/memcached_shadowserver.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["CATEGORY", "DESCRIPTION", "IP", "PORT", "ASN", "TIME", "GEOIP", "FQDN", "TAGS"]
    }

    mutate { convert => ["CATEGORY","string"]}
    mutate { convert => ["DESCRIPTION","string"]}
    mutate { convert => ["IP","string"]}
    mutate { convert => ["PORT","integer"]}
    mutate { convert => ["ASN","integer"]}
    mutate { convert => ["TIME","string"]}
    mutate { convert => ["GEOIP","string"]}
    mutate { convert => ["FQDN","string"]}
    mutate { convert => ["TAGS","string"]}

    json {
        source => "TAGS"
        target => "TAGS"
    }

}

output { 
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "test4"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Example of data

```
CATEGORY,DESCRIPTION,IP,PORT,ASN,TIME,GEOIP,FQDN,TAGS
vulnerable service,misconfigured memcached servers,10.10.10.10,11211,3000,February 27th 2018 15:46:23.000,SS,,{"tag":"DDoS","tag":"reflection","tag":"amplification","tag":"attack"}
```

Logstash log

```
[2018-03-17T00:16:44,182][WARN ][logstash.filters.csv     ] Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"vulnerable service,misconfigured memcached servers,10.10.10.10,11211,3333,February 24th 2018 13:19:12.000,SS,,{\"tag\":\"DDoS\",\"tag\":\"reflection\",\"tag\":\"amplification\",\"tag\":\"attack\"}", :exception=>#<CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.>}
```

Other than duplicate keys (which shouldn't matter I would think) the JSON is valid. And I checked another thread [Logstash does not parse json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753921/logstash-does-not-parse-json) where basically the same JSON format was used and apparently it worked.

Also ran my log without the JSON and then it works, so it has to be in there somewhere? Data shows up in Kibana as a message but nothing gets separated into fields.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thanks

I also tried to parse a log file which contained JSON that I had previously gotten to work.

```
CATEGORY,DESC,IP,GEOIP,ASN,TIME,PORT,DNS,TAGS
ics,Modbus protokolliga seadmed,80.235.16.222,EE,AS3249,2017-08-29T06:57:22.546423,1,kala.kalamees.ee,{"cms":"Drupal"} {"cve":"CVE-2018-0111"}
```

But now for some reason this JSON dosen't get parsed either. The other fields are properly parsed and can be searched in Kibana but nothing for the JSON even though I have previously gotten it to work with the same Logstash config..

Here is the log file which I've been using
https://github.com/jannoa/visualiseerimisplatvorm-DATA/files/1821633/test1.txt

Comment: The warning relates to csv parsing, not JSON parsing. You get this error: `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.` It might be something related to the fact that your JSON column in the csv has commas in it but is not surrounded by quotes.

Comment: @whites11 I checked up on that and have tried different formats, the latest one which I also linked at the end of the thread has no commas in the JSON column but still gives me `Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"iot,Paradox valvesüsteem,213.35.180.112,EE,AS3249,2017-08-29T03:12:08.200184,37,http://www.gpdi-lippocikarang.com ,{\"cms\":\"Drupal\"} ", :exception=>#<CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.>}` I feel like the config ignores JSON filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the problem is related to [default csv quote char](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.2/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-quote_char) that is the character `"`, that is present in the json field.

Try to set the `quote_char` to some values that is not present in your csv.

Comment: Thanks, setting `quote_char` to " ' " worked even though I've had no problems without it before.. Even though it's a different subject do you have any ideas for getting JSON formatted data into fields? I forgot that even though the data is searchable by string it's not in any fields like the rest of the data.